# Calculate the sum of geometrical progression

Tags: geometric-progressions

I have the following progression
$$
    \frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} + ... + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}
$$
I have that $a=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $q=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, then using $a\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$ I got $\frac{(1+x^2)^{n+1} - 1}{x^2(1+x^2)^{n+1}}$

My solution seems to be a bit hard and I think that it's possible to simplify the solution above. I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: I suppose you could reduce it to $$\frac1{x^2}-\frac1{x^2(1+x^2)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, yes, I did it. So do you think that there is no another way to write the sum using this formula?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The expression looks fine by itself. Why do you want such a simplification anyway?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, When I haven't an answer a simple solution says to me that I solved it correctly :-)

Comment: This works for $x\neq 0$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, Ok. Thank you very much for your help :-)

Comment: you must have $n$ in the powers instead of $n+1$.

Comment: Why do you think so? I use a formula where $q^{n+1}$ is used.

Comment: there are $n$ terms, so the formula is $a\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$.

Comment: It's not mandatory because in my case it is for the sum of the first (n+1) terms, your formula is for first n terms. I think it does not affect the solution.